# I want to Select from a table Where my id meets condition from a list

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I have a list and i want to select from my postgresql table data where condition meets data from my list.

I look around and i see the solution but it's not working on me. Also i have try to replace `IN` with `LIKE`, and `IN with ANY(%s)`

```
EnviromentalList = [59, 66, 67, 79, 144, 275, 276, 3096, 3097, 356, 376, 509, 548, 589, 871, 872, 888, 889, 890, 891, 901, 919, 960, 998, 221, 223, 224, 225, 226]

cur.execute("SELECT event_id, event_time FROM availabilitycalculation.machine_events WHERE event_id IN %s ;", (EnviromentalList,))

ErrorList = cur.fetchall()
```

I get:

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: Syntax error near "ARRAY"
>        line 1: ...ilitycalculation.machine_events WHERE event_id IN ARRAY[59,6...

Comment: You want `ANY()`

Answer (score 0):

To select rows that meet a condition in SQL, your use of operator will depend on the information you are trying to extract, and in this regard more detail from the database would be helpful to ascertain what specifically you are trying to accomplish.

**LIKE**

In this particular example, it looks like you wish to use the `LIKE` operator to select all instances of event IDs that end in the letter **s**. e.g. suppose I have a database of certain countries and wish to select ones that end in **d**.

```
select country from table where country like '%d';
   country   
-------------
 Ireland
 Finland
 Switzerland
(3 rows)
```

**ANY**

Now, let's take the example of `ANY`. This is used when we wish to select any entry that meets a specified condition. Coming back to the above example, suppose we are working with a hypothetical population table, and certain countries have higher populations than others.

We wish to select any country with a population greater than 10 million.

```
select country from table where country = any (select country from table where population>10000000);

   country   
-------------
 South Korea
 Brazil
 Spain
 Italy
 United Kingdom
(5 rows)
```

These are two examples of how `LIKE` and `AND` can be used, and for your case you should consider the specific information that you are trying to extract with each operator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I change my code with ANY and for parameter i take a new select that gives me back this list from another table of my database